# No rounded corners on React-Bootstrap-NavItem

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, react-bootstrap

I want to have the same look as the `pills` style but without the rounded corners

this is what i have so far

```
<style type="text/css">{`
.nav-pills > li + li {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
`}</style>
<Nav
     bsStyle="pills"
     justified
     activeKey={this.props.currentStep}
     onSelect={this.updateCurrentStep.bind(this)}
>
    <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Template">Template</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Edit">Edit</NavItem>
    <NavItem eventKey={3} title="Preview">Preview</NavItem>
</Nav>
```

How do I set the `border-radius` of my `NavItem` to 0? It does appear in the rules of the `li` item but it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your styling file, you can give:

```
.nav-pills>li>a {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

which should reset the styles of border radius to 0.

```js
const Nav = ReactBootstrap.Nav;
const NavItem = ReactBootstrap.NavItem;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Nav
          bsStyle="pills"
          justified
          activeKey={this.props.currentStep}
          onSelect={this.updateCurrentStep}
      >
          <NavItem eventKey={1} title="Template">Template</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={2} title="Edit">Edit</NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey={3} title="Preview">Preview</NavItem>
      </Nav>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.nav-pills>li>a {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.32.1/react-bootstrap.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different (and arguably better) ways to handle styling in React, but to use a style block like that you need to add `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:`

```
<style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
    .nav-pills > li + li { border-radius: 0 !important; }
`}} />
```

Comment: this does still not work, could you explain what the better ways to solve this problem would be?